# How to show the row index in row header in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

I am wondering in row in the datagridview,  How can i show the row index in the row header ?
Or you, guy, could guide me to the trick like i describe below.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each row header is HeaderCell after all so you can deal with it as `DataGridViewCell`:

```
For i = 0 To grd.RowCount - 1
    grd.Rows(i).HeaderCell.Value = CStr(i + 1)
Next
```